# Writing a new dao. No Hibernate Session bound to thread

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, transactional

So I have such classes

BaseDao

```
public interface BaseDao<T> {

    T save(T entity);  
}
```

UserDao

```
public interface UserDao extends BaseDao<User> {

    User getUserByUserName(String name);

}
```

GenericDao
public abstract class GenericDao implements BaseDao {

```
@Autowired
protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private Class<?> getEntityClass() {
    return ((Class) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
            .getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
}

public T save(T entity) {
    Integer id = (Integer) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(entity);
    return (T) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(getEntityClass(), id);
}
```

}

UserDaoImpl

```
@Repository
public class PgUserDaoImpl extends GenericDao<User> implements UserDao {

    public User getUserByUserName(String name) {
        Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(
                User.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", name));

        return (User) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }

}
```

GenericService

```
public class GenericService<T extends GenericDao<E>, E> {

    protected T dao;

    public GenericService(T dao) {
        setDao(dao);
    }

    @Transactional
    public E save(E entity) {
        return dao.save(entity);
    }
}
```

UserServiceImpl

```
@Service("userServiceImpl")
public class UserServiceImpl extends GenericService<PgUserDaoImpl, User>
        implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(PgUserDaoImpl dao) {
        super(dao);
    }

    @Autowired
    private UserAssebmler assebmler;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String name)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        .....
    }

}
```

So I write test contoller to save user, but I always get Exception
**org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here**

The contoller
@

```
Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceImpl userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "save", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test() {

        User user = new User();

        user.setName("admin");
        user.setPassword("21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3");
        user.setRole(UserRole.ADMIN);

        userService.save(user);

        return "home";
    }

}
```

Anybody know hot to fix that? Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post your spring configuration? It looks like you don't have a transaction manager or your transaction manager cannot bound a session due to configs.

Comment: yeah, here u are http://pastebin.com/UifbR3Rz
but before, when I wrote simple dao, all works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my question by extending GenericDao class from HibernateDaoSupport class.